# How to update nuget without changing version

Tags: nuget

I just published a package to nuget but realize I forgot to include a css file. My versioning is tied to the library I'm packaging (which I don't own) so I can't really increment it.

How do I force a re-push or what's the recommended thing to do in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out an answer to my own question.

There is apparently no limit on how many version places there are so you can simple append yet another version place.

So for example if the package you're packaging is `0.0.1` you can upload another one `0.0.1.1`

Comment: There is a limit to the number of version numbers. Only 4 are allowed: major.minor.patch.build